# Can we prevent tree from reusing item-rendrer?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, itemrenderer

i was in situation that tree is re-using my custom item-renderer.. is there any method or way around we can stop tree to reuse.. and always create a new item-renderer for new item.. thanx in advance..

Comment: Renderer Control will remains same for whole tree but its data will change node to node, is thats problem?, please explain in details

Comment: well thanks for help, I think it creates as many renderers as visible, and reuse them on scrolling..

Comment: I dont think it is possible to override item renderer recycling behaviour in list based controls.May I know why you would want to avoid recycling?

Comment: I have to keep record of selected renderer.. but when i again select that rendrer. or scroll down the selection is being set to other rendrer .

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need to keep track of the selected renderer and not the selectedItem ?  If you have a selected renderer, then you also have a selectedItem.  You can add a property to whatever data you have like "lastSelected=true" and then do your graphical processing in the renderer.